# Angular : problem when using component from library inside NgModule entryComponents array

Tags: angular

I have a **library** and a **showcase module** inside the same project.

The **library module** has a **PopoverService** and a **PopoverComponent**.

**PopoverService** uses **PopoverComponent** as the first parameter of the Angular CDK ComponentPortal constructor :

**PopoverService**:

```
open(...) {
    new ComponentPortal(
                    PopoverComponent,
                    // ...
    )
}
```

**Showcase module** uses **PopoverService** directly (but not **PopoverComponent**).

**Lib Module** is like this :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [PopoverComponent],
    imports: [
        // ... other modules
        OverlayModule
    ],
    providers: [PopoverService],
    exports: [PopoverComponent]
})
export class MyLibModule { }
```

**public-api.ts** is like this :

```
export * from './lib/my-lib.module';
```

And **Showcase Module** is like this :

```
import { PopoverComponent } from 'my-lib/lib/components/popover/popover.component';
@NgModule({
  // ... other
  imports: [
    // other modules
    MyLibModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [PopoverComponent]
})
export class ShowcaseModule { }
```

But I get this error when invoking PopoverService.open() :

```
./src/app/modules/showcase/showcase.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-lib/lib/components/popover/popover.component' in '........./src/app/modules/showcase'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add the Pop component as a separate export in your public APi. That way you can import it in your consuming module and add it to EntryComponents..

Comment: As a side note: if you need your pop service to be a singleton at all times, don’t provide it in your lib module but instead also separately export the service in public api...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly added PopoverComponent to the wrong module. Had to add

```
entryComponents: [PopoverComponent]
```

in the Library module not the consuming Showcase module. Still, I won't delete this question because of @MikeOne's valuable suggestions.